# BeforeClass using Spring transactional tests

Tags: unit-testing, hibernate, spring, junit

I'm using the Spring transactional test classes to do unit testing of my DAO code. What I want to do is create my database once, before all the tests run.  I have a @BeforeClass annotated method but that runs before Spring loads up the application context and configures the jdbcTemplate, thus I don't actually have a connection to the DB at that time.  Is there a way to run my DB setup once after the context loads but before the tests start running?

[This thead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/822846/setup-and-tear-down-of-complex-database-state-with-hibernate-spring-junit) asks the same question but the accepted solution seems to just be "don't do that".  I'm inclined to say this just seems like it isn't doable.

Comment: What was your solution?  How did you make it work?

Comment: I have since moved to Spring 3 and am using the jdbc:embedded-database xml tag to set up my database before the test runs. I also created a custom test execution listener that wraps DBUnit operations for validating/resetting the database state after each test case. See http://blog.zenika.com/index.php?post/2010/02/05/Testing-SQL-queries-with-Spring-and-DbUnit,-part-2

Comment: I just set it up, and BeforeClass annotated method runs after spring loads up the context..using testNG

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd second the advice that you should make each of your tests autonomous and therefore do all your setup with @Before rather than with @BeforeClass.

If you wish to stick with your approach just use the @Before method and have a simple boolean check to see if the setup has already been completed. e.g.

```
 if(!databaseSetup) {
    ...set up the database
    databaseSetup=true;
    }
```

Not too fancy but it will work!

See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/971483/spring-transaction-management-test/976741#976741) for an example spring transaction test with annotations using dbunit.

Hope this helps!

Comment: -1 because in fact this will NOT work because JUnit creates an instance of the test class for every method, thus your "databaseSetup" variable will always be false when entering the "@Before" method and you will still end up reinitializing the database before every test method.

Comment: That's true - thanks for pointing it out. I suppose you could use a static member variable but that's just getting deeper into the problem.

Comment: If you make you databaseSetup boolean static, this should work.

Answer (score 6):

my solution, a bit complicated but i needed it for an test framework :-)
do not be afraid of the german javadocs, the method names and bodies should be enough to get  it

**FIRST** create Annotation to mark Class or method for database work (create table and/or insert statements)

```
@Target({ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.METHOD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Inherited
@Documented
public @interface SchemaImport {

    /**
     * Location der Schemadatei(en). Die Datei darf nur SQL Statements enthalten.
     * Wird keine Location gesetzt, greift der Defaultwert.
     * @return String
     */
    String[] locationsBefore() default {"input/schemas/before.sql"};

    /**
     * Location der Schemadatei(en). Die Datei darf nur SQL Statements enthalten.
     * Wird keine Location gesetzt, greift der Defaultwert.
     * @return String
     */
    String[] locationsAfter() default {"input/schemas/after.sql"};

    /**
     * Ein SchemaImport findet nur bei passender Umgebungsvariable statt, mit diesem
     * Flag kann dieses Verhalten geändert werden.
     * @return boolean
     */
    boolean override() default false;
}
```

**SECOND** create listener which looks for the annotation, AbstractTestExecutionListener
is a Spring Framework Class from

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.springframework.test</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.6</version>
        </dependency>
```

```
public class SchemaImportTestExecutionListener extends AbstractTestExecutionListener
        implements ApplicationContextAware {

    /**
     * Standard LOG Definition.
     */
    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(
            SchemaImportTestExecutionListener.class);
    /**
     * Datasource Name - gemeint ist der Name der Datasource Bean bzw. die ID.
     */
    private static final String DATASOURCE_NAME = "dataSource";
    /**
     * JDBC Template.
     */
    private SimpleJdbcTemplate simpleJdbcTemplate;
    /**
     * Flag um festzustellen ob prepareTestInstance schon gerufen wurde.
     */
    private boolean isAlreadyPrepared = false;

    /**
     * Standard Constructor, laut API von konkreten Implementierungen für
     * TestexecutionListener erwartet, es geht aber auch ohne.
     */
    public SchemaImportTestExecutionListener() {
    }

    /**
     * Für jede Testklasse die mit der {@link SchemaImport} Annotation ausgezeichnet
     * ist, wird ein entsprechender SchemaImport durchgeführt.
     * 
     * Der SchemaImport findet pro Klasse exakt einmal statt. Diese Verhalten
     * entspricht der BeforeClass
     * Annotation von JUnit.
     * 
     * Achtung mit Nutzung von Schemaimport auf Klassenebene ist kein
     * Rollback möglich, stattdessen SchemaImport auf Methodenebene nutzen.
     *
     * @param testContext
     * @throws java.lang.Exception
     */
    @Override
    public void prepareTestInstance(TestContext testContext) throws Exception {
        final SchemaImport annotation = AnnotationUtils.findAnnotation(testContext.getTestClass(), SchemaImport.class);
        if ((annotation != null) && !isAlreadyPrepared && (isPropertyOrOverride(annotation))) {
            executeSchemaImports(testContext, annotation.locationsBefore(), true);
            isAlreadyPrepared = true;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Für jede Testmethode mit {@link SchemaImport} werden die angegebenen
     * Schema Dateien als SQL ausgeführt.
     *
     * @param testContext
     * @throws java.lang.Exception
     */
    @Override
    public void beforeTestMethod(TestContext testContext) throws Exception {
        // nur für Methoden mit passender Annotation Schemaimport durchführen
        final SchemaImport annotation = AnnotationUtils.findAnnotation(testContext.getTestMethod(), SchemaImport.class);
        if (annotation != null) {
            executeSchemaImports(testContext, annotation.locationsBefore(), true);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTestMethod(TestContext testContext) throws Exception {
        // nur für Methoden mit passender Annotation Schemaimport durchführen
        final SchemaImport annotation = AnnotationUtils.findAnnotation(testContext.getTestMethod(), SchemaImport.class);
        if (annotation != null) {
            executeSchemaImports(testContext, annotation.locationsAfter(), false);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Prüfen ob passende Umgebungsvariable gesetzt wurde. Diese kann durch
     * entsprechendes Setzen des Flags an der Annotation überschrieben werden.
     * @return
     */
    private boolean isPropertyOrOverride(SchemaImport annotation) {
        String prop = System.getProperty(TYPEnviroment.KEY_ENV);
        if (StringUtils.trimToEmpty(prop).equals(TYPEnviroment.EMBEDDED.getEnv())) {
            LOG.info("Running SchemaImport, Enviroment is set:'" + prop + "'");
            return true;
        } else {
            if (annotation.override()) {
                LOG.warn(
                        "Running SchemaImport, although Enviroment is set:'" + prop + "'");
                return true;
            } else {
                LOG.warn(
                        "Not Running SchemaImport cause neither Environment or SchemaImport.override are set.");
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Hilfesmethode die eigentlichen SchemaImport kapselt.
     *
     * @param testContext
     * @param locations
     */
    private void executeSchemaImports(TestContext testContext, String[] locations, boolean checkLocations) {
        // für jede Datei SchemaImport durchführen, korrekte Reihenfolge
        // ist durch Entwickler zu gewährleisten
        if (locations.length > 0) {
            for (String location : locations) {
                if (StringUtils.trimToNull(location) != null) {
                    if (isResourceExistant(location, checkLocations)) {
                        LOG.info("Executing Schema Location: '" + location + "'");
                        SimpleJdbcTestUtils.executeSqlScript(getJdbcTemplate(
                                testContext), new ClassPathResource(location),
                                false);
                    } else {
                        LOG.warn(
                                "Schema Location '" + location + "' for SchemaImport not found.");
                    }
                } else {
                    throw new RuntimeException("SchemaImport with empty Locations in:'" + testContext.getTestClass().getSimpleName() + "'");
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param resource
     * @return
     */
    private boolean isResourceExistant(String resource, boolean checkLocations) {
        try {
            new ClassPathResource(resource).getInputStream();
            return true;
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            if (checkLocations) {
                throw new RuntimeException(ex);
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Hilfsmethode um an ein JdbcTemplate heranzukommen.
     *
     * @param TestContext
     * @return SimpleJdbcTemplate
     */
    private SimpleJdbcTemplate getJdbcTemplate(TestContext context) {
        if (this.simpleJdbcTemplate == null) {
            this.simpleJdbcTemplate = new SimpleJdbcTemplate(getDataSource(
                    context));
        }
        return this.simpleJdbcTemplate;
    }

    /**
     * Hilfsmethode um an die Datasource heranzukommen.
     *
     * @param testContext
     * @return DataSource
     */
    private DataSource getDataSource(TestContext testContext) {
        return (DataSource) testContext.getApplicationContext().getBean(
                DATASOURCE_NAME, DataSource.class);
    }

    /** {@inheritDoc} */
    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext)
            throws BeansException {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
    }
}
```

**THIRD** add the listener to the test execution

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath*:spring/persistence/*.xml"})
@Transactional
@TestExecutionListeners({
    TransactionalTestExecutionListener.class,
    SchemaImportTestExecutionListener.class})
public abstract class AbstractAvHibernateTests extends AbstractAvTests {

    /**
     * SimpleJdbcTemplate für Subclasses verfügbar.
     */
    @Autowired
    protected SimpleJdbcTemplate simpleJdbcTemplate;
}
```

in use

```
@SchemaImport(locationsBefore={"schemas/spring-batch/2.0.0/schema-hsqldb.sql"})
public class FooTest extends AbstractAvHibernateTests {
}
```

its important to note - **beware of thread problems** while using testNg parallel testing, for this to work there should be some 'synchronized' markers for the getJdbcTemplate / dataSource Methods in the listener

ps:

the code for the test base class:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath*:spring/*.xml"})
@TestExecutionListeners({
    DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class,
    DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener.class,
    LogDurationTestExecutionListener.class,
    LogMethodNameTestExecutionListener.class})
public abstract class AbstractAvTests implements ApplicationContextAware {

    /**
     * Logger für Subclasses verfügbar.
     */
    protected final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());
    /**
     * {@link ApplicationContext} für Subclasses verfügbar.
     */
    protected ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    /** {@inheritDoc } */
    @Override
    public final void setApplicationContext(final ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
    }
}
```

LogDurationTestExecutionListener and LogMethodNameTestExecutionListener are custom listeners not provided by spring, but not needed for the schemaImport to work properly

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what unit testing framework you are using but for JUnit, you can make your test class subclass [AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests](http://static.springframework.org/spring/docs/2.5.6/api/org/springframework/test/context/junit4/AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests.html) which has an executeSqlScript method this can either be run in a beforeclass or beforemethod method. My preference is to use BeforeMethod as this means that each of my unit tests are autonomous, even if it means my unit tests run a bit slower.

Comment: I wouldn't be able to put this in a @BeforeClass method because @BeforeClass methods must be static and are run before the application context is loaded.

Comment: Ok, it is possible with TestNg if that is any help?

Answer (score -4):

Try using your old methods instead of the fancy annotations.

```
@BeforeClass
    public static void beforeClass() {
        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(
        "applicationContext.xml");
                  [...]
    }
```